# How to differentiate between user triggered touch event and programmatically triggered touch event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Suppose if I bind some event handler on click of some button, e.g.

```
$("#click-button").tap(function(event) {
    alert("clicked!!");
});
```

This can be invoked if user actually taps on that button or if I trigger same event using

```
$("#click-button").trigger('tap');
```

How to differentiate between these two events? If both are different then can I programmatically trigger event so that its considered as user action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event beign triggered has a property `isTrigger`. Just use that :

```
alert(!!event.isTrigger);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect `event.target` in your handler. You will be able to see the element that was clicked if it came from a touch event.